# Node tag as text with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have the following XML:

```
<DaysOfWeek>
    <MondayToSunday/>
</DaysOfWeek>
```

I'm using Nokogiri, if I call `node.name` it returns "text". How can I get the actual name of the tag, like "MondayToSunday"?

Comment: On Stack Overflow it's really important to show your attempt to solve the problem yourself. In this case it'd really help if you showed where you searched and why that search didn't provide you an answer. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". As it is, your question is pretty broad because we can't tell what you did to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element is already there with the tag name `MondayToSunday`. The issue is that when Nokogiri parses a document is also includes blank lines, that in your case you need to filter it out.

Here's an example:

```
# ex.rb

require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<-XML
<DaysOfWeek>
    <MondayToSunday/>
</DaysOfWeek>
XML

days_of_week = Nokogiri::XML(xml).children

days_of_week.children.each do |el|
  puts "Name: #{el.name}"
  p el.text
end
```

Then, when we run this example we can see that we actually have three children for the `DaysOfWeek` tag:

```
Name: text
"\n    "
Name: MondayToSunday
""
Name: text
"\n"
```

where there are two named `text` with new lines in them, and in between the tag `MondayToSunday`.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I had come to the same conclusion since asking the question, I have done this to resolve `day_of_non_operation.name if day_of_non_operation.type === Nokogiri::XML::Reader::TYPE_ELEMENT` so I only get the lines that are elements and not the text. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -2):

We can't tell how you're using Nokogiri, so it might be a simple mistake of doing it wrong. Here's what I'd do:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml =<<EOT
<DaysOfWeek>
    <MondayToSunday/>
</DaysOfWeek>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml)
doc.at('DaysOfWeek').name # => "DaysOfWeek"
doc.at('MondayToSunday').name # => "MondayToSunday"
```

`at` is a quick way to find the first node that matches a particular accessor, in this case, a node named "`DaysOfWeek`" or "`MondayToSunday`". Nokogiri is chock-full of ways to isolate a particular tag, which is its strength; Find it, get information about it, then move to the next one and repeat.

This is all in the regular documentation and in the [cheat sheet](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet).

Comment: This doesn't work unless you already know that a node exists with the tag 'MondayToSunday'

Comment: The point of the code was to show how to access a node correctly. Whether the node exists is beyond the example's purpose. And, because the OP didn't tell us how Nokogiri was being used, trying to cover every possible situation would be a tutorial which is why the question was closed as off-topic for the site.